# How to conditionally return an image reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a project currently in react and i'm trying to return an image if a condition is met, I've [looked into it](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and there is a few ways to do conditionals in react but I haven't seen any that will help me.
I'm using material-ui as well here is some of my code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { value: 1 };
}

handleChange = (event, target, value) => {
this.setState({ value });
};

render() {
return (
  <div className="background">
    <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange=
{this.handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Any" />
          <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="ex" />
          <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="am" />
          <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="p" />
          <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="l" />
          <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="e" />
        </DropDownMenu>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      <br />
```

I want to return an image if the value is 2 if its 4 I want a different image returned etc.

Comment: When you say "return an image", do you mean add a `leftIcon` or `rightIcon` prop? `<MenuItem value={2} primaryText="ex" leftIcon={<ContentLink />} />`

Comment: @Rick I mean return an image under the drop down, but thanks

Comment: It helps to include those details in the question then. You said you've "looked into it and there is a few ways to do conditionals"; post what you've tried. If you've read https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering then you should know everything there is to know.

Comment: Sorry about that @chipit24 this is my first question I have read through that, I just can't figure out how to bend it to do what I want it to, I'm not the best at react. I'm just asking for a little bit of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trivially add any conditionals into React render content. The cleanest way imho is to use inline ternary conditions:

```
<div>
  {
    this.state.value === 2 ? getImageFor2() : null
  }
  {
    this.state.value === 4 ? getImageFor4() : null
  }
</div>
```

Recall that returning `null` or `undefined` in React causes nothing to be rendered for that part.

You could also do it by taking advantage of how `&&`/`||` behave:

```
<div>
  {
    this.state.value === 2 && getImageFor2()
  }
  {
    this.state.value === 4 && getImageFor4()
  }
</div>
```

I personally prefer the first option since the second can lead to bugs in some cases if you are not careful with it.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried this before but must have made an error somewhere. None the less this works for me now.